# Initialized pointer has all 0's instead of generated values

Tags: c, pointers, null, malloc, sparse-matrix

I am implementing a sparse linear equation solver such as Lx = b. For this, I initialize a reference x vector named x_ref and generate an RHS vector b accordingly. However, both pointers seem empty somehow.

VALUE_TYPE is a macro and set to `double`

```
VALUE_TYPE *x_ref = (VALUE_TYPE *)malloc(sizeof(VALUE_TYPE) * n);
VALUE_TYPE *b = (VALUE_TYPE *)malloc(sizeof(VALUE_TYPE) * n);

for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    x_ref[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    for (int j = cscColPtrTR[i]; j < cscColPtrTR[i+1]; j++)
        {
            int rowid = cscRowIdxTR[j]; //printf("rowid = %i\n", rowid);
            b[rowid] += cscValTR[j] * x_ref[i];

        }
    }
```

After I print them as;

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("%d\t\t%d\n", x_ref[i], b[i]);
}
```

The results are:

```
4226166 1977719296
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
0       0
```

I cannot understand what is wrong with it.

Comment: What is `cscColPtrTR`? What does it contain?

Comment: @Inian since it is an sparse matrix, it has a special format which is CSC, compressed sparse column format. colPtr keeps the column indexes of non-zero elements, rowIdx contains the row indexes of non-zero elements and cscVal contains the actual values. However, x_ref is not dependent on it and still, it seems 0.

Comment: Use `%f` to print `double`. `%d` is for integers (with `%f` it seems to be OK https://godbolt.org/z/acNF9n)

Comment: @AlexLop. Oh :( I feel embarrassed... It is fine now, thank you! I guess after focusing on complex topics, people can miss this little things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Rather use objects in the `sizeof` instead of types `VALUE_TYPE *x_ref = (VALUE_TYPE *)malloc(sizeof(*x_ref) * n);`
2. Use the correct `printf` formats. `%d` is used to output integers, not doubles.

```
#define VALUE_TYPE double
int main(void)
{
    size_t n = 20;
    VALUE_TYPE *x_ref = malloc(sizeof(*x_ref) * n);
    VALUE_TYPE *b = malloc(sizeof(*b) * n);

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        x_ref[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d - %f\n", i, x_ref[i]);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/RKjZi8

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you don't need to cast those mallocs, since it returns a void pointer, so the cast is implicit. I'm not sure why you are getting those zeros, but there are some remarks:

- You need to seed the pseudo-random number generator:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) 
{ 
    // Use current time as seed for random generator 
    srand(time(0)); 

    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) 
        printf(" %d ", rand()); 

    return 0; 
}
```

- Initialize your b vector with a memset, because they are (as far as I can tell) accumulating values, so they should start from 0. As it is now, your vector may contain only gibberish.

I could not run your code because of the undefined references, but consider correcting those points :)